# Does Egoroff's Theorem hold for $E = (-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Egoroff's theorem states: Let ${f_j}$ be a sequence of measurable functions that converge to a real-valued function f almost everywhere on a measurable set E of finite measure, then given $\phi > 0$ there exists $A \subset E$ with $m(A) < \phi$ such that $f_j$ converges to f uniformly. Does this hold for $E = (-\infty, \infty)$? I cannot thinkn of a counterexample if this is not true.

Comment: You can render tex here... mostly just a matter of putting dollar signs around things and putting backslashes before the curly braces. Also I think you are missing an important qualifier after "$f_j$ converges to $f$ uniformly" (on what set?)

Comment: You should consider first whether uniform convergence is preserved on countable unions of sets.

Comment: Think a bump escaping to $+\infty$.

Comment: You did not state it correctly. You should have $f_j$ converging to $f$ uniformly on $E/ A$.

Answer (score 0):

It does not hold without the assumption $\mu(E)<\infty$.

Consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L},m)$. Let $E=[0,\infty)$, $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}x$ for $x\in E,\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $f(x)=0$ for $x\in E$. Then the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ everywhere on $E$. To see it does not converge to $f$ almost uniformly on $E$, we show that for any Lebesgue measurable subset $A$ of $E$ with $m(A)<\infty$, $\{f_{n}\}$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on $E\backslash A$. Let $m(A)<M$ where $M\in(0,\infty)$. Let $E_{k}=[(k-1)M,kM)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\{E_{k}\}$ is a disjoint sequence and $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}E_{k}=E$. Since $m(A)<M$ and $m(E_{k})=M$, there exists $x_{k}\in E_{k}$ such that $x_{k}\notin A$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{k}=\infty$. To show that $\{f_{n}\}$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on the subset $\{x_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $E\backslash A$, note that given $\varepsilon>0$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, and $n\geq N$ there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}x_{k}>\varepsilon$ so that $\lvert f_{n}(x_{k})-f(x_{k})\rvert=f_{n}(x_{k})=\frac{1}{n}x_{k}>\varepsilon$. This shows that $\{f_{n}\}$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on set $\{x_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset E\backslash A$.